# web scraper for emails and links

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, design-patterns, node.js, web-scraping

I created a class to scrape URLS, parse and validate emails and get internal links.

How can I achieve the SOLID principles in this class written in Javascript to make a web scraper?

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs')
const {
    JSDOM
} = require('jsdom');
class Scraper {
    static dangerDomains = ['loan', 'work', 'biz', 'racing', 'ooo', 'life', 'ltd', 'png'];
    static emailRegex = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi;
    static domObject = null;
    static internalLinks = new Set();
    static externalLinks = new Set();
    constructor(url) {
        this.url = url;
        this.emails = new Set();
        this.dangerEmails = new Set();
    }

    async executeScraper() {
        const fetchedData = await this.fetchUrlAndGetDom(this.url);
        const links = await this.getInternalLinks();
        const linksArray = Array.from(Scraper.internalLinks);
        const emails = await this.fetchInternalLinks(linksArray);
        this.addEmails(emails);
        this.validateEmails();
        await this.writeFile();
    }

    const result = async fetchInternalLinks(internalLink) {
        const result = await Promise.all(internalLink.map((link) => {
            return this.fetchUrlAndGetDom(`${this.url}${link}`);
        }));
        return result;
    }

    async fetchUrlAndGetDom(url) {
        try {
            const response = await axios(url);
            if (response.status === 200) {
                let htmlData = await response.data;
                Scraper.domObject = await new JSDOM(htmlData);
                let dades = this.searchForEmails();
                return dades;
            } else if (response.status === 404) {
                console.log('this page doesnt exists')
                return process.exit(1);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return process.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

> Get all the internal links from a website to scrape them

```
    getInternalLinks() {
        let links = Scraper.domObject.window.document.body;
        links = links.querySelectorAll('a[href^="/"]');
        Array.from(links).filter(link => Scraper.internalLinks.add(link.getAttribute('href')));
    }
```

> Use of a regex to find all the emails in the dom

```
    searchForEmails() {
        let emailsInDom = Scraper.domObject.window.document.body.innerHTML;
        let emails = emailsInDom.toString().match(Scraper.emailRegex)
        return emails;
    }
```

> Validate all the emails found in the dom

```
    validateEmails() {
        const validatedEmails = Array.from(this.emails).filter(email => {
            let domainName = email.split('@')[1].split('.')[1];
            if (Scraper.dangerDomains.includes(domainName)) {
                this.dangerEmails.add(email);
                this.emails.delete(email);
            } else return email;
        });
    }
```

> Write the emails in a file

```
    async writeFile() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.writeFile('./emails.txt', Array.from(this.emails), err => {
                if (err) reject('Could not write file');
                resolve('success');
            });
        });
    }
```

> Add email to the propertie emails

```
    addEmails(emailsInDom) {
        Array.from(emailsInDom).filter(el => {
            if(el !== null) {
                el.filter(el => this.emails.add(el))
      }
    });
    }
}
```

> This execute the scraper

```
const Scraper = require('./Scraper');
const scraper = new Scraper('any url');
(async () => {
  try {
    const dades = await scraper.executeScraper();

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})()
```

Comment: Opinion: you are using a class to encapsulate a library of web scraping utility functions.

Comment: It looks like you never call `getExternalLinks`. Is that deliberate, or is some of the code missing? Maybe edit in an example of how the class is used?

Comment: Scrapper != Scraper

Comment: I remove getExternalLinks because I don't use it. Also correct the orthography. I add the way that I execute the scraper. It's better to use functional programing or OOP in this case?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/250307/revisions#rev-arrow-8424d5f6-62c7-4eba-9ca2-bd4d92e39507) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: PS your email regex is woefully inadequate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/4400820

Answer (score 4):

I choose to focus on the Single Responsibility Principle in this answer.

To move closer to the Single Responsibility Principle, I think some of the functionality needs to be moved around. I have decomposed the class and removed all state that is shared on the class (rhetorical question: is the class responsible for state or functionality? If it is "both", then surely that violates SRP?!). Shared state like this can get tough to reason about and lead to an ever-larger class as the functionality evolves over time.

How about a `scraper` object, with one method `run` that accepts a URL and returns the result for a URL (and its sub-URLs)?

Usage:

```javascript
import scraper from './scraper.js'

const { emails: { valid, dangerous }, links: { internal } } = await scraper.run('http://www.example.com')
```

We configure a `result` object which we then pass around to populate, before it is returned:

```javascript
const scraper = {
    async run(url) {
        const result = {
            emails: { valid: [], dangerous: [] },
            links: { internal: [] }
        }
        return scrape(url, result)
    }
}
```

We define a `scrape` function, responsible for coordinating the scraping of a URL:

```javascript
async function scrape(url, result, visited=new Set()) {
    if (visited.has(url)) {
        return result
    }

    visited.add(url)
    const dom = await fetchDom(url)
    const internalLinks = findInternalLinks(dom)
    const { valid, dangerous } = validateEmails(findEmails(dom))

    for (let link of internalLinks) {
        await scrape(link, result, visited)
    }

    result.links.internal.push(...internalLinks)
    result.emails.valid.push(...valid)
    result.emails.dangerous.push(...dangerous)

    return result
}
```

Function `fetchDOM` is responsible for retrieving the DOM from the network for a URL:

```javascript
async function fetchDOM(url) {
    try {
        const { status, data } = await axios(url)
        switch (status) {
            case 200:
                return new JSDOM(await data)
            case 404:
                console.log('this page doesnt exists')
                return process.exit(1)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return process.exit(1)
    }
}
```

`findInternalLinks` is responsible for returning an array of internal links, found within the supplied DOM:

```javascript
function findInternalLinks({ window: { document: body } }) {
    let links = body.querySelectorAll('a[href^="/"]')
    return Array.from(links).map(link=>link.getAttribute('href'))
}
```

`findEmails` is responsible for returning the an array of emails, found within the supplied DOM:

```javascript
const EMAIL_REGEX = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi

function findEmails({ window: { document: { body: { innerHTML: html } } }) {
    return html.toString().match(EMAIL_REGEX)
}
```

`validateEmails` splits an array of emails into two sets: `valid` and `dangerous`:

```javascript
const DANGEROUS_DOMAINS = ['loan', 'work', 'biz', 'racing', 'ooo', 'life', 'ltd', 'png']

function validateEmails(emails) {
    const dangerous = []
    const valid = Array.from(emails).filter(email=>{
        let domainName = email.split('@')[1].split('.')[1]
        if (DANGEROUS_DOMAINS.includes(domainName)) {
            dangerous.add(email)
            return false
        } else
            return true
        })
    return { valid, dangerous }
}
```

The writing of a file is a wholly separate responsibility. Perhaps create an `emailFileWriter` object to encapsulate it:

```javascript
const emailFileWriter = {
    write(emails) {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            fs.writeFile('./emails.txt', emails, err=>{
                if (err) {
                    reject('Could not write file')
                }
                resolve('success')
            })
        })
    }
}
```

I would put each of these functions and objects in a separate file. Each has its own responsibility after all.

Answer (score 3):

### Bug: no assignment when calling `filter`

There are places where [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is called but not assigned to anything.

> ```
> Array.from(links).filter(link => Scraper.internalLinks.add(link.getAttribute('href')));
> ```

and this in `addEmails()`

> ```
> Array.from(emailsInDom).filter(el => {
>      if(el !== null) {
>          el.filter(el => this.emails.add(el))
>      }
> });
> ```

### Suggestions

#### Handling Response cases

The code in `fetchUrlAndGetDom()` handles responses of `200` and `404`. What about [the other numerous cases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)?

The `else` in that `if`/`else` sequence is superfluous, since the `if` block contains a `return` statement.

#### Variable declarations

It is recommended to default to using `const` instead of `let` for all variables as it can [cause bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/278652/244085). When you determine re-assignment is necessary (mostly for loop/iterator variables) then use `let`. Some variables are already declared with `const` but others could be declared with `const` instead of `let` - e.g. `htmlData` in `fetchUrlAndGetDom()`, `links` in `getInternalLinks()`, etc.

#### Variable naming

Some variables are inappropriately named. For example, the method `executeScraper` passes an array to the method `fetchInternalLinks`:

> const emails = await this.fetchInternalLinks(linksArray);

Yet the signature is:

> ```
> const result = async fetchInternalLinks(internalLink) {
>     const result = await Promise.all(internalLink.map((link) => {
>         return this.fetchUrlAndGetDom(`${this.url}${link}`);
>     }));
>     return result;
> }
> ```

Not only is `result` assigned to the function (which seems superfluous), the parameter is `internalLink`, yet it is passed an array and treated as an array (since the `.map()` method is called on it). A better name for that argument would be `internalLinks`.

#### NodeList to array

There are a few places where `Array.from()` is called to put elements of a NodeList to an array. Some of those can be simplified by using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). For example, instead of:

> ```
> Array.from(links).filter(link => Scraper.internalLinks.add(link.getAttribute('href')));
> ```

It can be:

```
[...links].filter(link => Scraper.internalLinks.add(link.getAttribute('href')));
```

#### Simplifying Regular Expressions

The Character class [`\w`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#Types) can be used instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. As was mentioned in a comment, [validating an email address with a regular expression is not an easy feat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/1575353). There are packages that could be used in NodeJS - e.g. [email-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-validator), [validate-email-address-node-js](https://github.com/bmshamsnahid/validate-email-address-node-js), etc.